# PLSQL - install works alternatively

Tags: plsql

I have a sql script file that I use to install tables, trigger, sequences and finally a package. The package uses the tables created by the sql script file. The package is specified to run when an event occurs in the application i.e the package runs when an application trigger is fired.

All the package does is that it does a bulk select insert into a staging table. That is all it does.

Now, the issue is when I do a clean install the first time, the package is triggered and runs but does not insert data into the staging table. However, when the next event occurs the package is triggered and data is inserted into the staging stable  and continues to function normally. So initially I thought it could be an initialization error.

However, when I drop all the objects created by the sql script file including the package and rerun the sql script file, the package works just fine when the first event occurs itself and continues to function normally.

So this cannot be an initialization error.

But again (just because I am losing my mind) I drop everything and rerun the script file, I find the same behavior I noticed the first time. Then I drop everything again and rerun the script file it works just fine the first time.

I have no idea why it works alternatively and this is so weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess code is in an invalid (un-compiled) state. A trigger is created on the table which calls a package which has not yet been created. Then the package is created. After first run, the trigger code is automatically re-compiled by the server. In your creation script, after all the objects are created, run a script to compile invalid objects (`ALTER <object> COMPILE`).

Verify that this is the case by checking:

```
SELECT object_type, object_name
  FROM all_objects
  WHERE status = 'INVALID'
```

after creation, but before your event triggers.

Comment: actually the table does not call the package. second thing is that when I ran the query for INVALID objects, it retruned 0 rows. I tried to use sleep() or even moved the installation of the package out of the script file. But the behavior repeats. I am planning to install this manually and see if I get the same behavior.

Comment: @Glenn....it was indeed an underlying synonym that was becoming INVALID evrytime I dropped the package. The synonym is created for the package. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. But I thought INVALID objects do not get recompiled automatically until they are compiled manually.

Comment: @user547453 Glad you found it. Can be frustrating to find. Take a look at [About Object Dependencies and Object Invalidation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/general007.htm#ADMIN12491) `Recompilation occurs automatically when the invalid dependent object is referenced.` When the invalid object is hit, an attempt is made to recompile, but the job that hit the invalid object still fails because it _was_ invalid. If compilation was successful, then the next hit ends up succeeding. A little further down, look at the `utl_recomp`: can be useful to run after an install script.